Is there any law that prohibits polygyny in the USA or Germany?
By polygyny, I mean religiously marrying more than one woman by a man.
Some religions allow marrying more than one woman. E.g., Islam, Mormonism, etc.
Is there any law that prohibits polygyny in the USA or Germany?
The law might say that there must be only one legal wife. That makes sense in terms of wealth splitting and child support.
However, is there any law in the USA or Germany that says that a man cannot religiously marry more than one woman and stay in the same house with them?

The usual sense of polyandry is a woman having more than one husband. The word for a man having more than one wife is polygamy...

@paulgarrett You mean "polygyny". "Polygamy" is multiple marriage, polygyny multiple women, polyandry multiple men.

You can have anyone wave their hands at you and say you're married, any number of times. But the legal effects of this will vary depending on jurisdiction and details, e.g. whether one or both parties believes it's a legitimate ceremony. It might be considered fraud in some circumstances.

I suspect it would be a violation of the 1st Amendment to prohibit any kind of religious marriage. The law only covers legal marriages. This is why Mormons can have religious polygyny, but only one of them is recognized legally.

Does a purely religious marriage have any legal status? I don't see how this would be different from three grown ups living together in an apartment. Who sleeps with whom is in general of no concern to the government.
